# Writing subscript in Mathjax?

Tags: mathjax

I want to type this .[image]

I have tried like this

```
$$\lambda=\frac{0.693}{t_\frac{1}{2}}$$
```

Also,

```
$$\lambda=\frac{0.693}{{t}_\frac{1}{2}}$$
```

Also,

```
$$\lambda=\frac{0.693}{t_{\frac{1}{2}}}$$
```

But it don't work it display something like this 
[image]

This code

[image]

also gives something that we don't want

[image]

Mathjax Configuration

```
<div class="layout"><script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  TeX: {extensions: ["AMSmath.js","AMSsymbols.js","mhchem.js","noErrors.js","noUndefined.js"]},
  tex2jax: {
      inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],
      displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ["\\[","\\]"] ],
      processEscapes: true
    },
});
</script>
<script src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML"></script>
```

Browser= Google Chrome
OS= Windows 8.1

Comment: Your last version renders fine on e.g. http://www.tuhh.de/MathJax/test/sample-dynamic.html and http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Wow all the the three codes works but it didn't work in mathjax .. Why??I am using the cdn given my mathjax documentation .. and how should i suppose the fix it?

Comment: are you sure it is actually parsing `$$...$$` construcitons? I do not remember if it does that by default.

Comment: @daleif should we enclose the mathjax tex codes inside $$..$$.. I have read that in http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I should perhaps say that most MathJax questions are off-topic here (read the tag wiki), so [so] would likely have been a better place for this question.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. ok how do i transfer it without rewriting again in stack overflow ?

Comment: You can't do that yourself, but you can flag it for moderator attention and ask for migration.

Comment: @user80946 it depends on the mathjax configuration. I don't knwo where you are testing. Since it just writes out everything, then the `$$...$$` parsing does not seem to be active. What happens if you just use `$...$` just to see if it will parse?

Comment: @daleif using $ ..$ and $$..$$ gives same result .. It don't render idk why :(

Comment: @daleif i have added mathjax configuration .

Comment: From the screenshot I'm guessing you are authoring in markdown which converts underscores into em tags -- and MathJax stops parsing at html tags. Adding spaces after the underscores often fixes this but it depends on the markdown parser you're using.

Comment: It would be better if you added the formula that's giving problems, not a random one. The screenshot has completely different things than the question. By the way, `$$\lambda=\frac{0.693}{t_{\frac{1}{2}}}$$` works flawlessly (tried on Math.SE).

Comment: Check http://jsfiddle.net/faf8oefz/

Comment: @egreg check it again i added one more screenshot :)

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger Yes yes i am using markdown . I use wordpress prase down based on daringfireball markdown.. Didn't know markdown affect such .. Can you say me what should i do ?

Comment: I'm guessing you mean pagedown which btw uses phpmarkdownplus. First I would confirm that this is happening by looking into the generated html source. Then as I already said, try adding a space after each underscore.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger you were correct when i looked source it shows like this <p>Half life $t<em>{\frac{1}{2}}$
$$\lambda=\frac{0.693}{t</em>{\frac{1}{2}}}$$</p>
<ul>  there is em .. So i should type $t_{\frac{1}{2}}$ this like this $t_ {\frac{1}{2}}$ ..added space still not working

Comment: Hm. Maybe try to replace them with `\_`?

Comment: Which markdown tool are you using again? My earlier comment about pagedown was nonsense; you probably meant parsedown in which case backslash escaping seems to work. Not ideal. You might want to ask the developers if they're willing to change its behavior to align with CommonMark (Which would be happy with spaces and thus your TeX source stays valid for real TeX.)

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger i use Parsedown for WordPress plugin

Answer (score 12):

**Use _{}**

> _{*`YOUR EXPRESSION`*}

**Example:**

```
$$Y_n = Y_{n-1}+{{(d/n)}sin(θ\pm n*Δ)}.$$
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`$$\frac{1}{\lambda}=\frac{0.693}{t_\frac{1}{2}}$$`

renders exactly what you are asking for and I tested it already.

Note the difference:

I just copied your first mathjax code:

`$$\lambda=\frac{0.693}{t_\frac{1}{2}}$$`

Note that before the '=' on the left side of the equation you just and simply wrote **\lambda** and that was your only mistake, so I simply replaced **\lambda** with **\frac{1}{\lambda}** and that's all.

You already showed us in your question that you already know that underscore _ renders subscript text and symbols in mathjax by the way.

Answer (score 1):

See the live example below:

```js
window.MathJax = {
  config: ["MMLorHTML.js"],
  jax: ["input/TeX", "input/MathML", "input/AsciiMath", "output/HTML-CSS", "output/NativeMML"],
  extensions: ["tex2jax.js", "mml2jax.js", "asciimath2jax.js", "MathMenu.js", "MathZoom.js"],
  asciimath2jax: {
    delimiters: [
      ['`', '`'],
      ['$', '$']
    ]
  },
  TeX: {
    extensions: ["AMSmath.js", "AMSsymbols.js", "noErrors.js", "noUndefined.js"]
  },
  tex2jax: {
    inlineMath: [
      ['$', '$'],
      ["\\(", "\\)"]
    ],
    processEscapes: true
  }
};
```

```css
.MathJax_CHTML {
  font-size: 30px !important;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" async src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML">
</script>
<p> $$\frac{1}{\lambda}=\frac{0.693}{t_\frac{1}{2}}$$</p>
<p> $$\frac{1}{\lambda}=\frac{0.693}{{t}_\frac{1}{2}}$$</p>
<p> $$\frac{1}{\lambda}=\frac{0.693}{t_{\frac{1}{2}}}$$</p>
```